# could not find function "sdf_quantile"

Tags: sparkr

```
quantile = sdf_quantile(ALL, ALL$otd_qty, probabilities = c(0.95),relative.error = 1e-05)
Error: could not find function "sdf_quantile"
```

I am getting error. I have also tried below code to get quantile:-

```
quantile = approxQuantile(ALL, ALL$otd_qty, probabilities = c(0.95),relative.error = 1e-05)
Error: could not find function "approxQuantile"
```

Comment: Please share a reproducible part of your code. Are you using `sparkR` or `sparklyr`? Have you loaded the packages before attempting to run the commands?...

Comment: Looks like you didn't load sparklyr. Try `require(sparklyr)`